# Unread message count in titlebar

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

I usually have Stack Overflow open in at least one tab throughout the workday which I will flip to occasionally during project compile times or breaks. Sometimes after a refresh I will see the red unread inbox count red in the notification bar, the only cue to indicate that you have messages.

This feature request would, in addition to the visual cue in the notification bar, prepend (or maybe append depending on how the browser renders tabs and titlebars) the unread message count to the titlebar text (via JavaScript for SEO purposes) to give a visual hint that there is possibly some activity (comment or otherwise) that could use some attention.

I hate to single out a giant company who does this already, but Facebook has this feature and I find it handier than it is annoying. I know not everyone will feel that way, but for users who like to stay on top of responding to comments and answers, it could be a nice tool.

Basic points, reiterated:

- Display unread message count as part of the titlebar
- Count would be appended (or prepended) via JavaScript
- Unread messages could be polled for on some interval. Perhaps the polling is only done after the browser window has lost focus to save on server requests.
- Titlebar count is modified as messages are marked read

The display format is open for discussion. One example for 3 unread inbox items:

> (3) Stack Overflow

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Ahh yes. I guess I didn't search hard enough before I posted.