# The [messages] this tag sends are ambiguous

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

There is a [messages](/questions/tagged/messages) tag with 67 questions and no excerpt/wiki, used for any sort of message. It seems rather ambiguous to me: there are plenty of specific *kinds* of messages that have more useful tags:

| More specific tag | Example question with [messages](/questions/tagged/messages) |
| --- | --- |
| [bounty-remarks](/questions/tagged/bounty-remarks) | [Why did my bullets fail to display as intended in my bounty message even they display properly temporarily sandboxed in an answer post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367883/) |
| [notifications](/questions/tagged/notifications) | [Why do I get a "hooray, your question was reopened" message when the question seem not to have been closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348088/) |
| [error-message](/questions/tagged/error-message) | [No error message is shown when trying to favorite a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56207/) |
| [edit-summary](/questions/tagged/edit-summary) | [Rollback reason message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214901/) |

And so on. When it's not being used in place of a more specific kind-of-message tag, it's being used like the [text](/questions/tagged/text) tag [was](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366648/), to indicate that the question is about specifically the text/message displayed within some context (example: [Don't say "Comment if you're trying to respond to an answer." when there's no answer, after clicking on "answer your question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350097/)).

([9 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmessages%5D+careers+is%3Aq) with the tag use it to refer to the messaging function within Careers, which is not on topic here)

This doesn't seem to be useful *at all* to me, but I'd be open to being convinced otherwise.

Comment: Agreed, should retag where possible and burninate the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tag no longer exists; the burnination is complete. Many [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) questions were closed as off-topic in the process due to being bumped.

Comment: Ayy, nice! But did you mean "messages" questions were closed instead of "jobs"? I don't see the [jobs] tag being mentioned anywhere in your original question.

Comment: Questions tagged with [tag:messages] that were closed since this burninate request was posted: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348088), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147279), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141255), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115065), [5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76400), [6](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34266), [7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31183).

Comment: @Spevacus I distinctly remember there being a significant number of Careers/Jobs questions with [messages]; perhaps they've been Roomba'd.